How to Fetch and Create Managed Content via API or Apex?
I'm working on an Integration and, need to Fetch and Create Managed Content (Product Media).

To fetch/get Managed Content data: I'm using API "/connect/cms/delivery/channels/channelId​/media/mediaGUID/content". But the problem with this is that it only returns the content data, not the extension. So, where can I find the content extension for file creation? or is there any other method to do so?

For Managed Content Creation: I've tried API "/connect/cms/contents" with v58.0, but I'm getting "You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request." as a response. So, How can I create Managed Content using API or Apex?


Any Info is appreciated.

please provide more information as to how you are making the request (e.g. what payload do you send to the POST request) for creation of the CMS content. Please note that you need to create your CMS workspace as an Enhanced CMS workspace for the request to be applicable https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_enhanced_cms_workspaces.htm&release=240&type=5

@Zlatin Zaltev, Thanks for the response. As for the POST request, I was sending the wrong payload in the request body, it turns out that to send binary data we need to set payLoad in a certain format. Refer to Inputs and Binary File Upload Examples. In the end I was able to create managed content at SF using the above method.

You need to obtain Managed Content Media Source Node Value
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_managed_content_media_source_node_value.htm
You can get it by using CMS Delivery, Channel Query
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_managed_content_delivery_channel.htm
In the response you would get Managed Content Version Collection
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_managed_content_version_collection.htm
which will have items array/collection of Managed Content Version
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_responses_managed_content_version.htm
which in turn will have contentNodes map, that will give you the Managed Content Media Source Node Value
